# ¿Cómo sacar la longitud de un array en Freemarker?

Tags: java, apache, template

Llevo ya un rato probando un montón de cosas que veo por internet acerca de como sacar la longitud de un array en `Freemarker`, pero ninguna funciona. Actualmente estoy trabajando en Java.

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente. Yo saco unos datos de la base de datos, esos datos son pasados a un fichero en formato JSON, y necesito saber la longitud de un array que contiene ese JSON, pero me está explotando todo el rato el programa.

La forma que he visto que es más fiable a la hora de querer sacar la longitud de un array, y la que estoy usando, es la siguiente:

```
<#assign count = 0>
<#list Tabla_ejemplo.rows as row>
    <#if count < (Tabla_ejemplo.rows?size) - 1>,
        "${row.dato}",
        <#assign count = count + 1>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Con esto lo que estoy intentando es mostrar todos los objetos de ese array menos el último, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo, pero salta el siguiente error:

```
For "?size" left-hand operand: Expected an extended-hash or sequence or extended collection, but this has evaluated to a collection
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error

> For "?size" left-hand operand: Expected an extended-hash or sequence
> or extended collection, but this has evaluated to a collection

se produce porque estas obteniendo la longitud de `Tabla_ejemplo.rows` y no de `Tabla_ejemplo`, realizalo de esta forma :

```
<#if count < (Tabla_ejemplo?size) - 1>,
```

Realiza los siguientes cambios:

```
<#assign count = 0>
<#list Tabla_ejemplo as row>
    <#if count < (Tabla_ejemplo?size) - 1>,
        "${row}",
        <#assign count = count + 1>
    </#if>
</#list>
```